# Calling the EventEmitter twice in the same class?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, events, module

I'm currently reading [a quick tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/nodejs-events-and-eventemitter/) on the `EventEmitter` in NodeJS. Here is one of the examples from that tutorial :

```
var events = require('events');

function Door(colour) {
  this.colour = colour;
  events.EventEmitter.call(this);

  this.open = function()
  {
  this.emit('open');
  }
}

Door.prototype.__proto__ = events.EventEmitter.prototype;

var frontDoor = new Door('brown');

frontDoor.on('open', function() {
    console.log('ring ring ring');
  });
frontDoor.open();
```

There's something I don't get. On the 5th line, we `call` the EventEmitter. If I'm not mistaken, this allows us to do things like that later on :

```
var myDoor = new Door('green');
myDoor.on('open', ...);
```

So basically it allows to use methods belonging to the `EventEmitter` class directly from an instance of the `Door` class, right ?

But then, what is the purpose of the 13th line of code (`Door.prototype.__proto__ = events.EventEmitter.prototype;`) ? This copies the properties of `EventEmitter` to the `Door` class. But wasn't that already done with the `call` method ?

I think I missed something... I hope you'll be able to help me understand all those things.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't have time to type up a proper answer right now, but basically the use of call is to handle any initial setup in EventEmitter's constructor. Assigning the prototype allows you to call its functions but they're going to fail when they try to access a property of the instance that was never initialised because you didn't execute the constructor.

Comment: Was in the process of typing up an explanation similar to that of @Bligglenuber (not going to put as an answer as my knowledge of Node is only sketchy, and I've never heard of `EventEmitter`). The one thing I would add, if you're familiar with OOP in other languages, is that calling `OtherFunction.call(this)` in a function `MyFunction` (assuming both are intended as "constructors") is essentially the prototype-based equivalent of `MyFunction` being a "subclass" of `OtherFunction` and calling `super` in the constructor of the subclass.

Comment: Why not use ES6 syntax for defining a new class and inheriting from `EventEmitter`?  It's way simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling the constructor allows you to use the parent function and substitute the child instance for `this`. This allows any initialization to happen, but it *doesn't* add the parent's prototype to the child function. Here's a simple example:

```js
function Parent(name){
  this.name = name
  this.somProp = "some prop for " + name
}

Parent.prototype.test = function(){
  console.log(this.name, "testing")
}

// use Parent:

let p = new Parent("parent instance")
p.test()


function Child(name){
  // call parent constructor puts `.somProp` on your instance
  Parent.call(this, name)
}

let c = new Child("C")
// child instance has somProp because we called the parent constructor
console.log(c)

// BUT THIS IS AN ERROR //
// becuase it doesn't inherit the prototype //

c.test()
```

By setting the `__proto__` property to the parent function prototype, you can now access the functions on the parent's prototype:

```js
function Parent(name){
  this.name = name
  this.somProp = "some prop for " + name
}

Parent.prototype.test = function(){
  console.log(this.name, "testing")
}

function Child(name){
  Parent.call(this, name)
}
Child.prototype.__proto__  = Parent.prototype

let c = new Child("C")
c.test()  // now this works
```

What's not really clear is if there is anything you need to initialize in the `EventEmitter` constructor. If you look through the docs you will see that the emitter sets `this` to the `EventEmitter` instance when a function is called. So you can look the the difference between the instances when you initialize the instance with `call` and when you don't. For example if you don't `call` the super class your instance won't have a `_maxListeners` which you probably want.

Comment: Thank you for this answer ! It was straight forward and I finally got to (really) understand what the `call()` function does.